# Docker : Multiple Instances for One MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, docker

Can we create multiple containers that host a single shared database in Docker, and if we can create it will we face any issues with that multiple instance on select event (for example)?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to use the right words for things, and put them together in a way that makes your question clear.  Docker has containers.  A container can run a mysql database.  You can have a swarm that runs 1000 mysql containers.  This is no different than running 1000 mysql servers.  If you did that, what problems would that create for your application?  Docker doesn't change the problems created by multiple mysql servers.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to paraphrase your question a bit. Please correct me if I have misunderstood anything.

**Q:** Can I run multi instances of MySQL database using `Docker` technology?

**A:**  Short answer: **Yes** because a `docker container` is just a `process` on your machine.

**Q:** If I have multi instances of MySQL database running on the same host, how does it know which instance am I performing my `query` on?

**A:** Well it all depends on the `connection string` you set for your database client.

Every database instances will have a corresponding `listener` process that is bind to a specific `port` of the host.

Now, each port can only be bind to a process. It is a 1 to 1 relation.

Essentially if you have 10 SQL instances installed, they will be bind to an unique port each. So the port number you defined in your `connection string` determines the database instance you'll be talking to.

Something worth noting is that, docker `containers`are self-contained. You can sort-of see them as conventional `virtual machine` except that they are much more light-weighted. That is, a container will have its own networking infrastructure, similar to your physical host. So for your physical host to be able to see the containerized database, you'll have to `port-forward` the bind port.

If the paragraph above doesn't make any sense to you then I'll recommend you to expore docker's `ports` or `-p` options for abit.

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: Thank's @Samuel Toh for your response. Assuming to have 3 containers of mysql that host the same database architectures (tables and relations) and a proxy, then my application will communicate with the proxy and this proxy redirects the request to one of these 3 instances depending on the availability of Resources of each  container, assuming I have a "select request from a specific table" how the proxy will interact,